# How to understand this assembly code with movl?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, mov

```
movl $0,-4(%rsp)  #t=0
leap -4(%rsp),%rax  #&t
```

I am confused with the meaning of `-4(%rsp)`. In the first line, it seems to represent the memory, but in the second line it seems to be the address. In my opinion, the first line should be `movl $0,(-4(%rsp))` Where am I wrong?

Comment: `lea` is load effective address. That's why you get the address. The at&t format is `displacement(base,index,scale)` you do not need extra parentheses.

Comment: Yes, so `-4(%rsp)` represents address, but to move 0 to the this address' location, we need to use `(-4(%rsp))` to represent that I am visiting this address's memory not the number of this address.

Comment: No, you don't need to add extra parentheses. `mov` knows to dereference the address.

Comment: The point is that the `lea` instruction is very special.  In all other instructions, `-4(%rsp)` does a load from memory and uses the loaded value as the operand (if a source), or takes the result of the computation and stores it to memory (if a destination).  But `lea` skips the load and instead uses the address itself as the operand.

Comment: Take the addressing modes in the context of the whole instruction, which informs whether an operand is a source vs. target, and whether a memory operation is involved or merely the address computation.

Comment: Parentheses around a register indicate a memory operand accessing memory.  `lea` is the one exception.